# how to draw a phasor diagram (like this picture)

Tags: diagrams, tikz-angles

[image]

Hi, I would like to draw this phase diagram as in the attached picture. But some examples I see in the internet are so different (more complex) and when I choose one way to follow I don't know how to add angles and letters as the picture too.

Here what I did since now (second picture):

```
    \usepackage{tikz} 
    \begin{document}        
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
    \draw[style=help lines] (0,0) (3,2);

    \coordinate (vec1) at (300:1.5); 
    \coordinate (vec2) at (30:2.5);
    \coordinate (vec3) at (0:2.5);
    \coordinate (vec4) at (90:2);
    \coordinate (vec5) at (270:2);
    \coordinate (vec6) at (180:2);

    \draw[->,thick,black] (0,0) -- (vec1);
    \draw[->,thick,black] (0,0) -- (vec2);
    \draw[->,thick,black] (0,0) -- (vec3);
    \draw[->,thick,black] (0,0) -- (vec4);
    \draw[->,thick,black] (0,0) -- (vec5);
    \draw[->,thick,black] (0,0) -- (vec6);

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \end document
```

[image]

Comment: Related Question: [How can I put the angle more right than I put here? And how can I make a subtitle also?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210756/how-can-i-put-the-angle-more-right-than-i-put-here-and-how-can-i-make-a-subtitl).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to learn about `arc` construction is to use the verbose mode at first. So the command

```
\draw [red, thick] (1.0,0) arc [start angle=0, end angle=30, radius=1cm]
    node [midway, right] {$\phi$};
```

says to start the arc at `(1.0,0)` with the provided parameters.  A more concise way of saying that is to use

```
\draw [red, thick] (1.0,0) arc (0:30:1cm)
    node [midway, right] {$\phi$};
```

where the parameter following the arc is `(<start angle>:<end angle>:<radius>)`.

[image]

### Code: Verbose

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{siunitx} 

\begin{document}        
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\draw[style=help lines] (0,0) (3,2);

\coordinate (vec1) at (300:1.5); 
\coordinate (vec2) at (30:2.5);
\coordinate (vec3) at (0:2.5);
\coordinate (vec4) at (90:2);
\coordinate (vec5) at (270:2);
\coordinate (vec6) at (180:2);

\draw[->,thick,black] (0,0) -- (vec1) node[right] {$I$};
\draw[->,thick,black] (0,0) -- (vec2) node[below right] {$V$};
\draw[->,thick,black] (0,0) -- (vec3) node [below] {$Re$};
\draw[->,thick,black] (0,0) -- (vec4) node [left] {$Im$};
\draw[->,thick,black] (0,0) -- (vec5);
\draw[->,thick,black] (0,0) -- (vec6);

\draw [red, thick] (1.0,0) arc [start angle=0, end angle=30, radius=1cm]
    node [midway, right] {$\phi$};    

\draw [blue, thick] (0.5,0) arc [start angle=0, end angle=-60, radius=0.5cm]
    node [midway, right] {$\phi-\ang{90}$};    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Code: Concise:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{siunitx} 

\begin{document}        
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\draw[style=help lines] (0,0) (3,2);

\coordinate (vec1) at (300:1.5); 
\coordinate (vec2) at (30:2.5);
\coordinate (vec3) at (0:2.5);
\coordinate (vec4) at (90:2);
\coordinate (vec5) at (270:2);
\coordinate (vec6) at (180:2);

\draw[->,thick,black] (0,0) -- (vec1) node[right] {$I$};
\draw[->,thick,black] (0,0) -- (vec2) node[below right] {$V$};
\draw[->,thick,black] (0,0) -- (vec3) node [below] {$Re$};
\draw[->,thick,black] (0,0) -- (vec4) node [left] {$Im$};
\draw[->,thick,black] (0,0) -- (vec5);
\draw[->,thick,black] (0,0) -- (vec6);

\draw [red, thick ] (1.0,0) arc (0:30:1cm)    node [midway, right] {$\phi$};    
\draw [blue, thick] (0.5,0) arc (0:-60:0.5cm) node [midway, right] {$\phi-\ang{90}$};  

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Command `AngleMark` has several options to mark the angles in different ways.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,tikz,siunitx} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
MarkAngleDim/.store in=\MarkAngleDim,
MarkAngleDim=0.5,
MarkDim/.store in=\MarkDim,
MarkDim=2,
}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\AngleMark}{%
d<>     % secteur si vide ou traits avec le nombre de traits
O{}     % options de dessin
m       % liste des angles A/B/C
O{0}    % nb de marques
D<>{7pt}        % décalage du node
}{%
\foreach \Bn/\An/\Cn in {#3} {%
    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints%
    {\pgfpointanchor{\An}{center}}%
    {\pgfpointanchor{\Bn}{center}}%
    \let\AnglA\pgfmathresult ;
    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints%
    {\pgfpointanchor{\An}{center}}%
    {\pgfpointanchor{\Cn}{center}}%
    \let\AnglB\pgfmathresult ;  
    \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(\AnglA>\AnglB,\AnglA-360,\AnglA)}          \global\let\AnglA\pgfmathresult ;   

\IfNoValueTF{#1}{% Secteur à remplir
    \path[very thin,#2] (\An) --
        ($(\An) !\MarkAngleDim cm!(\Bn)$)
        arc (\AnglA:\AnglB:\MarkAngleDim)
                    node[pos=.5] (@ngle\Bn\An\Cn) {}
        --cycle;}{% Trait simple
    \path[very thin,#2] ($(\An) !\MarkAngleDim cm!(\Bn)$)
        arc (\AnglA:\AnglB:\MarkAngleDim)
                    node[pos=.5] (@ngle\Bn\An\Cn) {} ;
}
    % Node de quotation sur l'arc
    \node (Angle\Bn\An\Cn) at
        ($(@ngle\Bn\An\Cn)!-#5!(\An)$) {} ;

\ifnum#4>0

    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints%
    {\pgfpointanchor{\An}{center}}%
    {\pgfpointanchor{Angle\Bn\An\Cn}{center}}%
    \let\AnglC\pgfmathresult ;

    \begin{scope}[shift={(\An)}]
    \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \ang
                using \AnglC+2*(\i-#4/2-.5)/\MarkAngleDim]
    in {1,...,#4} {%
    \draw[very thin,#2] (\ang:\MarkAngleDim cm +\MarkDim pt)
                    --(\ang:\MarkAngleDim cm -\MarkDim pt) ;
    }
    \end{scope}
\fi
}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}        
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\draw[style=help lines] (0,0) (3,2);

\coordinate (vec1) at (300:1.5); 
\coordinate (vec2) at (30:2.5);
\coordinate (vec3) at (0:2.5);
\coordinate (vec4) at (90:2);
\coordinate (vec5) at (270:2);
\coordinate (vec6) at (180:2);

\draw[->,thick,black] (0,0) coordinate (O) -- (vec1);
\draw[->,thick,black] (0,0) -- (vec2);
\draw[->,thick,black] (0,0) -- (vec3);
\draw[->,thick,black] (0,0) -- (vec4);
\draw[->,thick,black] (0,0) -- (vec5);
\draw[->,thick,black] (0,0) -- (vec6);

\AngleMark[draw,MarkAngleDim=.8]{vec3/O/vec2}
\node at (Anglevec3Ovec2) {$\phi$};

\AngleMark[draw]{vec1/O/vec3}<0pt>
\node[anchor=north west] at (Anglevec1Ovec3) {$\theta=\phi-\ang{90}$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

one more solution:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta,quotes,angles}
\usepackage{siunitx}
    \begin{document}
%%%% se-phasor
\begin{tikzpicture}[
            > = angle 90,
phasor/.style = {very thick,-{Triangle[fill=white]}},
angles/.style = {draw, <->, angle eccentricity=1, 
                 right, angle radius=7mm}
                        ]
% coordinates
    \draw[->] (-0.5,0) -- (4,0) coordinate (x) node[below left] {$Re$};
    \draw[->] (0,-1.5) -- (0,2) node[below left] (y) {$Im$};
% phasors
    \draw[phasor] (0,0) -- (300:1.5) coordinate (i)  node[right] {I};
    \draw[phasor] (0,0) -- ( 30:2.5) coordinate (v)  node[right] {V};
% angles drawn by pic
\coordinate (X)   at (0,0);
\draw
    pic["$\theta=\phi-\SI{90}{\degree}$",angles] {angle=i--X--x}
    pic["$\phi$",angles] {angle=x--X--v}
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version of the original diagram in [Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it), with the text set in Times New Roman using the XITS font and the [`luamplib`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/luamplib) package.

You have to process this with `lualatex`, but this approach brings Unicode and OTF font handling to plain Metapost.  Notice that you can still redefine things (like the arrowheads) as required.

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{XITS}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}

    % redefine "_finarr" to get unfilled arrows
    def _finarr text t =  
      draw _apth t;
      unfill arrowhead _apth;
      draw arrowhead _apth  t
    enddef;

    beginfig(1);

      path xx, yy, vv, ii;

      % axes
      yy = (40 down -- 40 up);
      xx = (15 left -- 120 right);
      drawarrow(xx); label.bot(btex \textit{Re} etex, point infinity of xx);
      drawarrow(yy); label.lft(btex \textit{Im} etex, point infinity of yy);

      % vectors
      phi = 28;
      theta = phi - 90;
      vv = origin -- 90 right rotated phi;
      ii = origin -- 40 right rotated theta;
      drawarrow(vv); label.rt(btex \textbf{V} etex, point infinity of vv);
      drawarrow(ii); label.rt(btex \textbf{I} etex, point infinity of ii);

      % angle marks
      path angle_mark[];
      angle_mark1 = fullcircle scaled 70 cutafter vv;
      angle_mark2 = reverse fullcircle scaled 30 cutafter ii;
      draw(angle_mark1); 
      draw(angle_mark2); 
      label.rt(btex $ϕ$       etex, point .5 of angle_mark1 + 2 up);
      label.rt(btex $θ=ϕ-90°$ etex, point .5 of angle_mark2 + 4 down);

    endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```