# How can I put the angle more right than I put here? And how can I make a subtitle also?

Tags: positioning, diagrams, tikz-angles

Is it possible to adjust the angle more than I did: [ABOVE RIGHT]

```
\draw [black, thick] (0.7,0) arc [start angle=0, end angle=110, radius=0.7cm]
        node [above right] {$\theta=\phi-\ang{90}$};
```

I'd like to remove it from the y axis and put it in more right than it is.

And How can I make a subtitle under this figure?

> Voltage and current phasor of a capacitor.

[image]

```
    \usepackage{tikz}   
    \usepackage{siunitx} 

    \begin{document}

    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
    \draw[style=help lines] (0,0) (3,2);

    \coordinate (vec1) at (110:2); 
    \coordinate (vec2) at (20:4);
    \coordinate (vec3) at (0:4.5);
    \coordinate (vec4) at (90:2.5);
    \coordinate (vec5) at (270:1.5);
    \coordinate (vec6) at (180:3);

    \draw[->,thick,black] (0,0) -- (vec1) node[below left] {$\hat{I}$}; 
    \draw[->,thick,black] (0,0) -- (vec2) node[below right] {$\hat{V}$};
    \draw[->,thick,black] (0,0) -- (vec3) node [below] {$Re$};
    \draw[->,thick,black] (0,0) -- (vec4) node [right] {$Im$};
    \draw[->,thick,black] (0,0) -- (vec5);
    \draw[->,thick,black] (0,0) -- (vec6);

    \draw [black, thick] (1.3,0) arc [start angle=0, end angle=20, radius=1.3cm]
    node [midway, right] {$\phi$}; 
    \draw [black, thick] (0.7,0) arc [start angle=0, end angle=110, radius=0.7cm]
    node [above right] {$\theta=\phi-\ang{90}$};

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Please complete your code with `\documentclass`, the relevant packages and `\begin{document}... \end{document}`. Beyond that, could you please explain what you mean? Which angle? More right with respect to what? What have you adjusted it with respect to? I am not sure what you mean by 'subtitle'. Documents sometimes have subtitles. Do you just want a caption? If so, use `\begin{figure}\centering\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}\caption{My caption}\end{figure}`, for example.

Comment: Related Question: [How to draw a phasor diagram (like this picture)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210727/how-to-draw-a-phasor-diagram-like-this-picture).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The initial point of the angle needs to be located along the line, so using polar coordinates `(20:0.7)` is the easiest way to specify that:

[image]

To add a caption you can use the `caption` package. Alternatively you can add a `\node` to place text below the axis.

### Notes:

- I added rotation to the blue node as that seemed the easiest way to display the text.
- If you don't want the `Figure 1` use `\captionof*`

---

If you don't like the `rotation`, you can apply an `xshift` to shift the label over. So, with

```
node [midway, above right, xshift=-1.0em] {$\theta=\phi-\ang{90}$}
```

you obtain:

[image]

---

## Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage{caption} 

\begin{document}     
{\centering   
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
    \draw[style=help lines] (0,0) (3,2);

    \coordinate (vec1) at (110:2); 
    \coordinate (vec2) at (20:4);
    \coordinate (vec3) at (0:4.5);
    \coordinate (vec4) at (90:2.5);
    \coordinate (vec5) at (270:1.5);
    \coordinate (vec6) at (180:3);

    \draw[->,thick,black] (0,0) -- (vec1) node[below left] {$\hat{I}$}; 
    \draw[->,thick,black] (0,0) -- (vec2) node[below right] {$\hat{V}$};
    \draw[->,thick,black] (0,0) -- (vec3) node [below] {$Re$};
    \draw[->,thick,black] (0,0) -- (vec4) node [right] {$Im$};
    \draw[->,thick,black] (0,0) -- (vec5);
    \draw[->,thick,black] (0,0) -- (vec6);

    \draw [red, thick] (1.3,0) arc [start angle=0, end angle=20, radius=1.3cm]
    node [midway, right] {$\phi$}; 
    \draw [blue, thick] (20:0.7) arc [start angle=20, end angle=110, radius=0.7cm]
        node [midway, right, rotate=45] {$\theta=\phi-\ang{90}$};
    \node [below, color=black] at (270:1.5) {Voltage and current phasor of a capacitor. (via node)};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\captionof*{figure}{Voltage and current phasor of a capacitor. (via captionof)}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot, Peter. I have another question now that is if it is possible to remove the name Figure 1 from the caption?

Comment: @FranciscoMaerle: Have updated solution to eliminate the `Figure `:` and also to show how you can shift the node text.